# How to display count in a listview of a row with few column details in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

following is the code that i am trying out to get the details of the application name (KEY_NAME), application_category (KEY_CATEGORY) and application_permissions(KEY_PERM)

**but really what i want is with the application name and category to display the number of permissions(count)** how can i do that i display it in the list view

handler

```
public Cursor queueAll() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CATEGORY,
                "count" + KEY_PERM };
        Cursor cursor = sqlitedb.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null,
                KEY_NAME, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

main activity

```
mySQLiteAdapter = new Handle(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
        String[] from = new String[] { Handle.KEY_NAME, Handle.KEY_PERM,
                Handle.KEY_CATEGORY };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.appname, R.id.numbpermcount, R.id.category };
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.activity_main_row, cursor, from, to);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

thank you in advance.

i tried to do it again as this.

Handler

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "application_name";
public static final String KEY_PACK = "application_package";
public static final String KEY_PERM = "application_permission";
public static final String KEY_LEVEL = "application_level";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "application_category";

public Cursor queueAll() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CATEGORY,
                "count(" + KEY_PERM +")" };
        Cursor cursor = sqlitedb.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null,
                KEY_NAME, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Main Activity

is as the same as above...

ERROR

```
02-19 22:51:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{db.database/db.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'application_permission' does not exist
```

Comment: Won't `count(permissions)` have to be a sub-query?

Comment: i think your columns need to be like this : String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CATEGORY,
                "count(" + KEY_PERM+")" };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is a little beyond what can be done with the builtin `query` method. Instead, you'll need `rawquery`, to which you can pass arbitrary SQL. It sounds like you need

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "application_name";
public static final String KEY_PACK = "application_package";
public static final String KEY_PERM = "application_permission";
public static final String KEY_LEVEL = "application_level";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "application_category";

public static final String KEY_PERM_COUNT = "application_permission_COUNT";

public Cursor queueAll() {
    Cursor cursor = sqlitedb.rawquery(
        "SELECT "+KEY_ID+", "+KEY_NAME+", "+KEY_CATEGORY
        +", count("+KEY_PERM+") AS "+KEY_PERM_COUNT
        +" FROM "+MYDATABASE_TABLE
        +" GROUP BY "+KEY_ID+", "+KEY_NAME+", "+KEY_CATEGORY
    );
    return cursor;
}
```

And then set up your adapter to also read the `Handle.KEY_PERM_COUNT`.

Comment: thank you mate... it works fine. thank you alot for teaching me about raw query. :)